# Proving that if $|A| = |B|$, then $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = |\mathcal{P}(B)|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that if $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, then their power sets have the same cardinality. Here is my attempt.

> As $|A| = |B|$, there exists a bijection $f: A \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} B$. Define $\Omega: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ by $\Omega(S) = f(S)$. I claim that $\Omega$ is a bijection. Indeed, fix $S \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. As $f$ is bijective and hence surjective, then for each $s \in S$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = s$. Then $T := \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in S\} = f^{-1} (S) \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. (If $S = \emptyset$, then $T = \emptyset$.) It then follows that $f(T) = S$. Indeed, if $s \in S$, then $T$ contains the unique preimage, $a \in f^{-1} (\{s\})$, by construction, so $f(a) = s \in f(T)$ and hence $S \subset f(T)$. Conversely, if $y \in f(T) = f(f^{-1} (B))$, then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in T = f^{-1} (S)$. Therefore, $y = f(x) \in S$, giving the opposite inclusion, so $\Omega$ is surjective. Now, suppose that $\Omega(C) = \Omega(C')$ for $C,C' \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Then $f(C) = f(C')$. That is, $f^{-1} (C) = f^{-1} (C')$. As $f$ is injective, we deduce that $C = C'$, so $\Omega$ is injective. Therefore, $\Omega$ is bijective and we have $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = |\mathcal{P}(B)|$.

I'm having trouble explaining why $f^{-1} (C) = f^{-1} (C')$, but I know it's a consequence of injectivity. How does this look?

Comment: Maybe I'm naive, but I always thought the cardinality of a power set depends only on the cardinality of the set.

Comment: @herb That's exactly what they're trying to prove.

Comment: You need to show that $\Omega(C) = \Omega(C')$. I think you can show these sets are equal directly by a double containment proof and I think it will rely on the surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: @ShawSa I still don't see what there is to prove.  Cardinality is number sets.  Power set is cardinality of all combinations of subsets.  What needs to be proved, since both A and B have the same cardinality?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I think the OP isn't working with the definition that incorporates cardinal numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Comparing_sets. The definition they're working with requires them to show a bijection exists between the two power sets given that it exists between the two sets. They have the correct bijection, they're just working through it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake. $C\in P(A)$ and $f : A \to B$, so $f^{-1} : B \to A$ cannot take $C$ as argument.

Comment: No I mean, $C$ must be an element of $P(B)$.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The number of subsets of a set $A$ equals the number of functions from $A$ to a $2$-element set.  That's it's $\lvert 2^A\rvert $.  That in turn only depends on the order of $A$.  That's $\lvert 2^A\rvert =2^{\lvert A\rvert }$.

(This is true for both finite and infinite cardinals.  Correction:  now I'm told that this requires the axiom of choice)